# Spinner personalizado en android

Tags: android, spinner

Tengo un desplegable en mi aplicación con un estilo. A parte dentro de un relative layout le puse un `EditText` para que aparezca una flecha como si fuera un desplegable, orientada a la derecha y y que ocupe el alto del desplegable pisa el desplegable. Visualmente queda bien, el problema es que cuando pulsas en la flecha (`editText`) no se despliega. No sé si se puede poner alguna transparencia al `editText` para que detecte lo que hay debajo. o quizá un onClick en el Editext que lo despliegue.

Adjunto código del layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerMatricula"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_circle_gris"
            android:elevation="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/EtV"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinnerMatricula"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerMatricula"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerMatricula"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_circleflecha"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/fondos"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:text=" v "
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Si pulsas por el medio funciona perfectamente.

Gracias.

Comment: una pregunta, el proposito del textview es que este dentro del spinner cuando apretas la flecha y se te muestren los resultados, o es algo que se muestra fuera del spinner

Comment: @mabts Disculpa veo que te refieres a que tienes un "EditText" para que aparezca una flecha como si fuera un desplegable, ¿Te refieres al "TextView" que esta en el código que agregaste?. Saludos.

Comment: Hola. Si el TextView. no EditText. El proposito del textView es que el de que aparezca como una flecha. pero no consigo que al pulsar se despliegue el spinner.

Comment: Hola. Conseguí solucionarlo. Con un evento onclick en el TexView. E indicarle la siguiente propiedad. `nombreDelSpinner.performClick();`